# Converting Java bytes to C++

Tags: c++, qt

I work with Qt/C++ and I rewrite my Java project in Qt/C++ , so I could not convert these codes to C++

Java:

```
public static String getByteValueArr(String item)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(byte b : item.getBytes())
      sb.append(String.valueOf(b) + " ");

   return sb.toString();
}
```

I used this in C++

```
int MainWindow::getVal(QChar *word)
{
   return word->digitValue();
}
```

But it returns like

I know that C++ doesn't contain "byte" definition. So I could not convert this method in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use `QString`-s or `std::string`-s?

Comment: Qt or C++ ? What did yo try?

Comment: A `byte` in java is equivalent to `char` in C++.

Comment: @fritzone both of them. I use Qt creator IDE.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I tried, But it does not converts byte values like 65, 13 ...

Comment: @ratchetfreak thanks but how can we use .getBytes() in c++ ?

Comment: @TarıkİNCE In this case please also respond to Basile's question: do you use `QString` or `std::string`? And also, show us some code so that we can see your first attempt.

Comment: @fritzone I edited. Please check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is the C++ type that represents a single byte.

Strings can be built either appending to them, or using a `stringstream` (which is similar to a `StringBuilder`). Their characters can be iterated over directly. So the C++ equivalent would be along the lines of

```
#include <string>

std::string getByteValueArr(std::string const & item) {
    std::string result;                      // or std::stringstream ss;
    for (int c : item) {
        result += std::to_string(c) + ' ';   // or ss << c << ' ';
    }
    return result;                           // or return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your Java code correctly, this should be the C++ equivalent

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string getByteValueArr(const std::string& item)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (char c : item)
        ss << int(c) << " ";

    return ss.str();
}
```